# How come the Oracle query cannot find table, when it can reach other tables of same ownership?

Tags: c#, linq, oracle, entity-framework

I have two identical queries (but looking at different tables), using Entity-Framework, calling the Oracle database, one will be able to find the table, but the other does not.

```
using(CarContainer Cars = new CarContainer()) {
    var carModel = from c in temp.Cars.OfType<BMW>() orderby c.ID select c.MODEL;
}



using(CarContainer Cars = new CarContainer()) {
    var carModel = from c in temp.Cars.OfType<BENTLEY>() orderby c.ID select c.MODEL;
}
```

When I run the second query, it gives me "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

I opened up SQL Plus, using the same credentials, and did a `select * from BENTLEY` and it gave me the table.

Comment: You're using a jealous german data access provider ?

Comment: Compare the grants on these two tables by `SELECT * FROM SYS.DBA_TAB_PRIVS p WHERE p.TABLE_NAME in ('BMW', 'BENTLEY') ORDER BY p.TABLE_NAME` and see if there are differences.  Issue any grants needed to make the privileges on BENTLEY match the privileges on BMW.

Comment: Figured it out, somehow when I put in the grant permission, it didn't go through, but the others did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I used my *grants.sql* file, one of the grant commands did not get successfully passed to the Oracle Database.

I added in `GRANT ALL ON CHOWNER.BENTLEY TO ADMINROLE;` and it worked again!